pdf viewr not work Cannot resolve symbol 'barteksc'
i taken a project and uploaded the files but pdfviewer not work and i have uploaded the gradle files but still no work
package com.dimension.a3dimension;


import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnLoadCompleteListener;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnPageChangeListener;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnPageErrorListener;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.scroll.DefaultScrollHandle;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.util.FitPolicy;
import com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfDocument;



import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;


public class QuickManualActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnPageChangeListener, OnLoadCompleteListener,
        OnPageErrorListener {

    private static final String TAG = QuickManualActivity.class.getSimpleName();


    public static final String SAMPLE_FILE = "user_manual_arabic.pdf";
    public static final String READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE";


    PDFView pdfView;


    Integer pageNumber = 0;

    String pdfFileName;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quick_manual);
        Toolbar toolbar =  findViewById(R.id.appToolbarQuick);
        TextView toolbarTitle = findViewById(R.id.toolbarTitleQuick);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final ActionBar supportActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (supportActionBar != null) {
            supportActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            supportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            supportActionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back);
            toolbarTitle.setText("User Manual Arabic");
        }

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(v -> onBackPressed());
        pdfView = findViewById(R.id.pdfView);

        displayFromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE);

        setTitle(pdfFileName);


    }





    private void displayFromAsset(String assetFileName) {
        pdfFileName = assetFileName;

        pdfView.fromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE)
                .defaultPage(pageNumber)
                .onPageChange(this)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                .onLoad(this)
                .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
                .spacing(10) // in dp
                .onPageError(this)
                .pageFitPolicy(FitPolicy.BOTH)
                .load();
    }



    @Override
    public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount) {
        pageNumber = page;
        setTitle(String.format("%s %s / %s", pdfFileName, page + 1, pageCount));
    }



    @Override
    public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
        PdfDocument.Meta meta = pdfView.getDocumentMeta();
        Log.e(TAG, "title = " + meta.getTitle());
        Log.e(TAG, "author = " + meta.getAuthor());
        Log.e(TAG, "subject = " + meta.getSubject());
        Log.e(TAG, "keywords = " + meta.getKeywords());
        Log.e(TAG, "creator = " + meta.getCreator());
        Log.e(TAG, "producer = " + meta.getProducer());
        Log.e(TAG, "creationDate = " + meta.getCreationDate());
        Log.e(TAG, "modDate = " + meta.getModDate());

        printBookmarksTree(pdfView.getTableOfContents(), "-");

    }

    public void printBookmarksTree(List<PdfDocument.Bookmark> tree, String sep) {
        for (PdfDocument.Bookmark b : tree) {

            Log.e(TAG, String.format("%s %s, p %d", sep, b.getTitle(), b.getPageIdx()));

            if (b.hasChildren()) {
                printBookmarksTree(b.getChildren(), sep + "-");
            }
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onPageError(int page, Throwable t) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Cannot load page " + page);
    }

}


package com.dimension.a3dimension;


import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnLoadCompleteListener;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnPageChangeListener;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnPageErrorListener;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.scroll.DefaultScrollHandle;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.util.FitPolicy;
import com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfDocument;



import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;


public class DetailedManualActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener, SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener,
          {

    private static final String TAG = QuickManualActivity.class.getSimpleName();


    public static final String SAMPLE_FILE = "user_manual_english.pdf";
    public static final String READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE";


    PDFView pdfView;


    Integer pageNumber = 0;

    String pdfFileName;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detailed_manual);
        Toolbar toolbar =  findViewById(R.id.appToolbarDetailed);
        TextView toolbarTitle = findViewById(R.id.toolbarTitleDetailed);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final ActionBar supportActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (supportActionBar != null) {
            supportActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            supportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            supportActionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back);
            toolbarTitle.setText("User Manual (English)");
        }

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(v -> onBackPressed());
        pdfView = findViewById(R.id.pdfView2);

        displayFromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE);

        setTitle(pdfFileName);


    }





    private void displayFromAsset(String assetFileName) {
        pdfFileName = assetFileName;

        pdfView.fromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE)
                .defaultPage(pageNumber)
                .onPageChange(this)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                .onLoad(this)
                .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
                .spacing(10) // in dp
                .onPageError(this)
                .pageFitPolicy(FitPolicy.BOTH)
                .load();
    }



    @Override
    public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount) {
        pageNumber = page;
        setTitle(String.format("%s %s / %s", pdfFileName, page + 1, pageCount));
    }



    @Override
    public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
        PdfDocument.Meta meta = pdfView.getDocumentMeta();
        Log.e(TAG, "title = " + meta.getTitle());
        Log.e(TAG, "author = " + meta.getAuthor());
        Log.e(TAG, "subject = " + meta.getSubject());
        Log.e(TAG, "keywords = " + meta.getKeywords());
        Log.e(TAG, "creator = " + meta.getCreator());
        Log.e(TAG, "producer = " + meta.getProducer());
        Log.e(TAG, "creationDate = " + meta.getCreationDate());
        Log.e(TAG, "modDate = " + meta.getModDate());

        printBookmarksTree(pdfView.getTableOfContents(), "-");

    }

    public void printBookmarksTree(List<PdfDocument.Bookmark> tree, String sep) {
        for (PdfDocument.Bookmark b : tree) {

            Log.e(TAG, String.format("%s %s, p %d", sep, b.getTitle(), b.getPageIdx()));

            if (b.hasChildren()) {
                printBookmarksTree(b.getChildren(), sep + "-");
            }
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onPageError(int page, Throwable t) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Cannot load page " + page);
    }

              @Override
              public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int i, int i1) {

              }

              @Override
              public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

              }

              @Override
              public void onPageSelected(int position) {

              }

              @Override
              public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

              }
          }


the gradle files
Note: i was try implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'
and implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2' but still not work
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {

    namespace 'com.dimension.a3dimension'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dimension.a3dimension"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {

        release {

            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }

    }

    compileOptions {

        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources.excludes.add("META-INF/*")
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
}

dependencies {


    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

    /*hc-05*/
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games-v2:20.1.2"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.AnyChart:AnyChart-Android:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'

    implementation 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'

    implementation 'com.github.felHR85:UsbSerial:6.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.mik3y:usb-serial-for-android:3.5.1'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics")
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.2'

    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2"
    // For control over item selection of both touch and mouse driven selection
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0"

    implementation 'com.github.AsynctaskCoffee:VideoLayout:1.3'
    implementation 'bg.devlabs:fullscreen-video-view:1.2.0'
    implementation 'cn.jzvd:jiaozivideoplayer:7.7.0'


    implementation 'com.github.Foysalofficial:pdf-viewer-android:2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.2.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.6.1'


}

pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com/"
            allowInsecureProtocol = true
        }
        maven { url 'https://jcenter'}
        maven { url 'https://www.myget.org/F/abtsoftware/maven' }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "3DIMENSION"
include ':app'


that is all
